# Wrap content over a block and make it flow around it?

Tags: html

Is it possible to create an effect with HTML5/CSS or even a bit of JS that mimics an obstacle with the 'fluid' content 'flowing' around it? [image]

Like a block div element with a specified width and height that is centered in the middle of the window and all other content dynamically adjusts and "avoids" the div as we scroll down. The div stays in the center of the screen at all times.

```
<div id="centerblock"></div>

<p>Donec ut vestibulum velit. Sed lorem enim, malesuada tristique lacinia eget, tempus eu libero. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.Praesent et risus ut neque suscipit sollicitudin vel tristique diam. Nulla molestie sagittis est, gravida aliquet leo faucibus in. Suspendisse volutpat cursus est sed bibendum. Mauris bibendum et eros in malesuada. Nunc rutrum ligula ut vehicula varius.
</p>
..More <p> paragraphs..
```

And the CSS I tried:

```
#centerblock {
  width:200px;
  height:60px;
  background:green;
  margin:auto;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0;
  display:inline-block;
}
* {
  z-index:1;
}
```

Trying to build that effect but I'm not sure if it is feasible at all: http://codepen.io/power-inside/pen/yyPzrO

Comment: none that I'm aware of. seems like a complicated feature. what is your reason to do this?

Comment: @Timmerz Just trying to create a fancy effect..

Comment: yeah, I imagine that would be quite complex. I'd look into a collision detection library and you'll have to figure out all the math and resizing, etc. let me know if you achieve the effect you want. I'd be interested in seeing the result.

Comment: @Timmerz Yeah I guess I'll have to go with that approach..

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/ronansmith/u6dtsL6x/

```
.inside-block {
    float: left;
    width: 60px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

this can make words around the div in 3 directions. Or you can use `float:  right;` make the div stay in right.